# Using mean and median in a tbl dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe, mean, median

I am using a table dataframe 'tbl_df' and the dplyr library to summarise a list of integers by date using the following statement

```
daily<- group_by(dt.activity, date)
```

The structure of 'daily' is as follows:

```
Classes ‘grouped_df’,‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and'data.frame':15264 obs.of 3 variables:  
$ steps   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ date    : Date, format: "2012-10-02" "2012-10-02" "2012-10-02" ...
$ interval: int  0 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 ...
```

For 'sum' this works fine

```
sumDailySteps <- summarise(daily, sum(steps))
```

For 'mean' this works fine

```
meanDailySteps <- summarise(daily, mean(steps))
```

For 'median' it is a different story as all the values are set to zero and makes nonsense of a barplot

```
medianDailySteps <- summarise(daily, median(steps))
```

I would be grateful of any ideas why sum and mean are successful but median is not.

Comment: Is it possible that over 1/2 the values are zero?  If so, the median would be zero.  You would get more assistance by providing reproducible data for someone to work with.

Comment: @aka That is an interesting point thanks. Here is a link to the data in question
[https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/repdata%2Fdata%2Factivity.zip](https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/repdata%2Fdata%2Factivity.zip)

Comment: So over 1/2 the values of your steps column are zero, which implies that at least some dates are the same. That would be why you are getting funky looking values from plotting the medians.

Comment: @aka. I see what you mean    
    x<-c(0,0,0,0,2,4)
    median(x)
    [1] 0  
So now I'm off to find a way to impute or remove them. Thanks again for your help